# How to get responsive columns to fill across first rather than down in Next.js / Tailwind?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, vercel

Modifying the [Next.js Image Gallery starter](https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/image-gallery-starter) in an effort to practice full stack dev with Next.js. Was looking to create a chronlogical photo gallery of a recent trip I went on, but the issue is that the responsive column layout is filling down the columns first rather than progressing accross, so the resulting image gallery (which is over 400 pictures) is on the first line showing the 1st, 101th, 201th, and 301th indexed images as the 4 across the top. Not only is throwing the chronology off visably, I'm sure it's not very good on performance either. Curious if there's a way to fill across responsive rows first and  perhaps also how to better load in the large image package from the asset manager for a quicker, more performative load?

index.tsx (commented out is the test I used to show pictures of it moving down columns as it progresses through the array):

```
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
import Heading from '../components/Heading'
import Modal from '../components/Modal'
import cloudinary from '../utils/cloudinary'
import getBase64ImageUrl from '../utils/generateBlurPlaceholder'
import type { ImageProps } from '../utils/types'
import { useLastViewedPhoto } from '../utils/useLastViewedPhoto'

const Home: NextPage = ({ images }: { images: ImageProps[] }) => {
  const router = useRouter()
  const { photoId } = router.query
  const [lastViewedPhoto, setLastViewedPhoto] = useLastViewedPhoto()
  // const test = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

  const lastViewedPhotoRef = useRef<HTMLAnchorElement>(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    // This effect keeps track of the last viewed photo in the modal to keep the index page in sync when the user navigates back
    if (lastViewedPhoto && !photoId) {
      lastViewedPhotoRef.current.scrollIntoView({ block: 'center' })
      setLastViewedPhoto(null)
    }
  }, [photoId, lastViewedPhoto, setLastViewedPhoto])
  
  return (
    <>
      <Heading />
      <main className="mx-auto max-w-[1960px] p-4">
        <div>
            <h1 className="mt-8 mb-4 text-base font-bold uppercase tracking-widest">
              Four Pass Loop
            </h1>
            <h2>
              Maroon Bells Wilderness
            </h2>
            <h3>
              Aspen, CO
            </h3>
            <p>
              August 03 - 06, 2023
            </p>
        </div>
        {photoId && (
          <Modal
            images={images}
            onClose={() => {
              setLastViewedPhoto(photoId)
            }}
          />
        )}
        <div className="columns-1 gap-4 sm:columns-2 xl:columns-3 2xl:columns-4">
          {images.map(({ id, public_id, format, blurDataUrl }) => (
            <Link
              key={id}
              href={`/?photoId=${id}`}
              as={`/p/${id}`}
              ref={id === Number(lastViewedPhoto) ? lastViewedPhotoRef : null}
              shallow
              className="after:content group relative mb-5 block w-full cursor-zoom-in after:pointer-events-none after:absolute after:inset-0 after:rounded-lg after:shadow-highlight"
            >
              <Image
                alt="Mac photo"
                className="transform rounded-lg brightness-90 transition will-change-auto group-hover:brightness-110"
                style={{ transform: 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)' }}
                placeholder="blur"
                blurDataURL={blurDataUrl}
                src={`https://res.cloudinary.com/${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME}/image/upload/c_scale,w_720/${public_id}.${format}`}
                width={720}
                height={480}
                sizes="(max-width: 640px) 100vw,
                  (max-width: 1280px) 50vw,
                  (max-width: 1536px) 33vw,
                  25vw"
              />
            </Link>
          ))}
          {/* {test.map((element) => (
            <div>
              {element}
            </div>
          ))} */}
        </div>
      </main>
      <footer className="p-6 text-center text-white/80 sm:p-12">
        Built and shot by {' '}
        <a
          href="https://macgotsch.com/"
          target="_blank"
          className="font-semibold hover:text-white"
          rel="noreferrer"
        >
          Mac Gotsch
        </a>{' '}
      </footer>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home

export async function getStaticProps() {
  const results = await cloudinary.v2.search
    .expression(`folder:${process.env.CLOUDINARY_FOLDER}/*`)
    .sort_by('public_id', 'asc')
    .max_results(500)
    .execute()
  let reducedResults: ImageProps[] = []

  let i = 0
  for (let result of results.resources) {
    reducedResults.push({
      id: i,
      height: result.height,
      width: result.width,
      public_id: result.public_id,
      format: result.format,
    })
    i++
  }

  const blurImagePromises = results.resources.map((image: ImageProps) => {
    return getBase64ImageUrl(image)
  })
  const imagesWithBlurDataUrls = await Promise.all(blurImagePromises)

  for (let i = 0; i < reducedResults.length; i++) {
    reducedResults[i].blurDataUrl = imagesWithBlurDataUrls[i]
  }

  return {
    props: {
      images: reducedResults,
    },
  }
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.5.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.4",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.13",
    "cloudinary": "^1.32.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.0.1",
    "framer-motion": "^7.6.4",
    "imagemin": "^8.0.1",
    "imagemin-jpegtran": "^7.0.0",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hooks-global-state": "^2.0.0",
    "react-swipeable": "^7.0.0",
    "react-use-keypress": "^1.3.1",
    "sharp": "^0.33.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@svgr/webpack": "^8.1.0",
    "@types/node": "18.11.9",
    "@types/react": "18.0.25",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "daisyui": "^4.4.23",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.1.13",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.1",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  }
}
```

Pictures of the columns-priority fill on an example arrray 1-20:

- [4 column fill in fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rX3jc.png)
- [2 column in split screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/846FN.png)

Any feedback would be helpful, here to learn!

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using a [grid layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids) instead of a [CSS columns layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_multicol_layout).

This is creating the column layout:

```html
<div className="columns-1 gap-4 sm:columns-2 xl:columns-3 2xl:columns-4">
```

And an equivalent grid layout would be:

```html
<div className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 sm:grid-cols-2 xl:grid-cols-3 2xl:grid-cols-4">
```

Comment: I gave that a try and it certainly solved the chronological order issue, but revealed another: that the gallery is comprised of both portrait and landscape shots (that ideally will both be able to be shown uncropped) and portrait shots in any row with a landscape leads to a nasty gap beneath it before the next grid. Do you think something like a CSS flexbox might better suit my needs?

Comment: No, you'd want a [masonry grid](https://masonry.desandro.com/) but [native masonry grids are not yet supported in any browsers yet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Masonry_layout).

Comment: So is there no way to do what I'm looking to do that's supported? I'm just confused because the [Next.js starter template](https://nextjsconf-pics.vercel.app/) that I forked the code directly from seems to have indices filled across rather than down, which is ultimately what I want.

Comment: In my original answer, the indices would be filled across rather than down.